# Undefined Reference to 'gdopen' on HDF-EOS2

Tags: fortran, hdf

I am trying to build HDF-EOS2 for an Ubuntu 20.04 system and for Fortran, and have been following the steps presented in here https://www.hdfeos.org/software/hdfeos.php.

All of the dependencies of HDF-EOS2 were built from source and are installed in a non-default directory. The version of the dependencies for HDF4 that I use are the following:

- ZLIB (1.2.11)
- SZIP (2.1.1)
- JPEG (9e)

No additional options were added upon installing these--the only option that I used was the `--prefix`.

For installing HDF4 2.16-2, I used the following options:

`--with-zlib=$ZLIB_DIR --with-jpeg=$JPEG_DIR --with-szlib=$SZIP_DIR --prefix=$HDF4_DIR --enable-fortran`

I am trying to build it with `--enable-shared` but without much success, I am told by the error log to disable Fortran if I were to generate a shared library. Finally, I built HDF-EOS2 3.0 with the following options:

`--prefix=$HDFEOS_DIR CC=h4cc --with-szlib=$SZIP_DIR --enable_fortran`

Comparing with the tutorial above, I have removed the `-Df2cFortran` option for the CC variable because it doesn't seem to do anything and the `enable-install-include` option is unrecognized. The installation was successful. However, when I try to call `gdopen` from a Fortran code, it returns an `undefined reference to 'gdopen'` error.

I have no idea why this occurs because I have linked the `hdfeos` library (which defines `gdopen`) when compiling the Fortran code (let's call it `read_hdfeos.f90`). The options for compilation are shown below,

`h4fc -fno-underscoring -L$(HDFEOS_DIR)/lib read_hdfeos.f90 -lhdfeos -lGctp -o read_hdfeos.exe`

Comment: ", I am told to disable Fortran if I were to generate a shared library. " By whom? Why?

Comment: It was part of the error message--the HDF4 cannot compile with shared libraries while Fortran is enabled and is asking to disable Fortran instead. Since I will be working with Fortran, I opted to disable the shared libraries instead.

Comment: Oh HDF4, ok. It is quite old, isn't it? Normally, HDF5 is now used for new software.